# stream_socket_client() working on localhost but not on aws server for "tcp://mx00.mail.com:25" to validate email

Tags: email-validation, stream-socket-client

We are trying to validate the email on our website and skip filling in the fake email on the quote form by the end user. we are using stream_socket_client() to check the "tcp://mx00.mail.com:25" It's working fine on our localhost Xampp Server but when we are deploying it to the live server it gets stuck and returns the timeout.

```
 public function check($email) { 
        $result = FALSE; 

        if (!self::validate($email)) { 
            $this->set_error("{$email} incorrect e-mail"); 
            $this->edebug($this->ErrorInfo); 
            if ($this->exceptions) { 
                throw new verifyEmailException($this->ErrorInfo); 
            } 
            return FALSE; 
        } 
        $this->error_count = 0; // Reset errors 
        $this->stream = FALSE; 

        $mxs = $this->getMXrecords(self::parse_email($email)); 
        $timeout = ceil($this->max_connection_timeout / count($mxs)); 
        foreach ($mxs as $host) { 
            /** 
             * suppress error output from stream socket client... 
             * Thanks Michael. 
             */ 
            $this->stream = @stream_socket_client("tcp://" . $host . ":" . $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout); 
            if ($this->stream === FALSE) { 
                if ($errno == 0) { 
                    $this->set_error("Problem initializing the socket"); 
                    $this->edebug($this->ErrorInfo); 
                    if ($this->exceptions) { 
                        throw new verifyEmailException($this->ErrorInfo); 
                    } 
                    return FALSE; 
                } else { 
                    $this->edebug($host . ":" . $errstr); 
                } 
            } else { 
                stream_set_timeout($this->stream, $this->stream_timeout); 
                stream_set_blocking($this->stream, 1); 

                if ($this->_streamCode($this->_streamResponse()) == '220') { 
                    $this->edebug("Connection success {$host}"); 
                    break; 
                } else { 
                    fclose($this->stream); 
                    $this->stream = FALSE; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        if ($this->stream === FALSE) { 
            $this->set_error("All connection fails"); 
            $this->edebug($this->ErrorInfo); 
            if ($this->exceptions) { 
                throw new verifyEmailException($this->ErrorInfo); 
            } 
            return FALSE; 
        } 

        $this->_streamQuery("HELO " . self::parse_email($this->from)); 
        $this->_streamResponse(); 
        $this->_streamQuery("MAIL FROM: <{$this->from}>"); 
        $this->_streamResponse(); 
        $this->_streamQuery("RCPT TO: <{$email}>"); 
        $code = $this->_streamCode($this->_streamResponse()); 
        $this->_streamResponse(); 
        $this->_streamQuery("RSET"); 
        $this->_streamResponse();
        $code2 = $this->_streamCode($this->_streamResponse()); 
        $this->_streamQuery("QUIT"); 
        fclose($this->stream); 
        
        $code = !empty($code2)?$code2:$code;
        switch ($code) { 
            case '250': 
            /** 
             * http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0821.txt 
             * 250 Requested mail action okay, completed 
             * email address was accepted 
             */ 
            case '450': 
            case '451': 
            case '452': 
                /** 
                 * http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0821.txt 
                 * 450 Requested action not taken: the remote mail server 
                 * does not want to accept mail from your server for 
                 * some reason (IP address, blacklisting, etc..) 
                 * Thanks Nicht Lieb. 
                 * 451 Requested action aborted: local error in processing 
                 * 452 Requested action not taken: insufficient system storage 
                 * email address was greylisted (or some temporary error occured on the MTA) 
                 * i believe that e-mail exists 
                 */ 
                return TRUE;
            case '550':
                return FALSE; 
            default : 
                return FALSE; 
        } 
    }
```

For Reference: [Click Here](https://www.codexworld.com/verify-email-address-check-if-real-exists-domain-php/)